# Buildozer fails for kivy due to Cython compilation error on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, kivy, cython, buildozer

I am unable to get the Buildozer compilation to work for my kivy script. Currently have Ubuntu 14.04.

```
~$ python -V
Python 3.4.3
~$ cython -V
Cython version 0.21
~$ buildozer --version
Buildozer 0.32
```

Not sure if I have the right setup here or if there it is some sort of configuration that I am not aware of.
Please point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Snippet of the log:

```html
ccache arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/kerbi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -DNDEBUG -DANDROID -mandroid -fomit-frame-pointer --sysroot /home/kerbi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm -fPIC -I/home/kerbi/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9c/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include -I/First/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/include/python2.7 -c kivy/graphics/vertex_instructions.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/kivy/graphics/vertex_instructions.o

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    #    c) create BezierSpline subclass that does the computation

    cdef list _points
    cdef int _segments
    cdef bint _loop
    cdef int _dash_offset, _dash_length
                          ^
------------------------------------------------------------

kivy/graphics/vertex_instructions.pyx:107:27: '_dash_length' redeclared 

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        `mode`: str
            Mode of the vbo. Check :attr:`mode` for more information. Defaults to
            'points'.

    '''
    cdef list _vertices
             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

kivy/graphics/vertex_instructions.pyx:297:14: C attributes cannot be added in implementation part of extension type defined in a pxd

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        `mode`: str
            Mode of the vbo. Check :attr:`mode` for more information. Defaults to
            'points'.

    '''
    cdef list _vertices
             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

kivy/graphics/vertex_instructions.pyx:297:14: '_vertices' redeclared 

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
            Mode of the vbo. Check :attr:`mode` for more information. Defaults to
            'points'.

    '''
    cdef list _vertices
    cdef list _indices
             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

kivy/graphics/vertex_instructions.pyx:298:14: C attributes cannot be added in implementation part of extension type defined in a pxd

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
            Mode of the vbo. Check :attr:`mode` for more information. Defaults to
            'points'.

    '''
    cdef list _vertices
    cdef list _indices
             ^
------------------------------------------------------------

kivy/graphics/vertex_instructions.pyx:298:14: '_indices' redeclared 

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
            'points'.

    '''
    cdef list _vertices
    cdef list _indices
    cdef VertexFormat vertex_format
                     ^
------------------------------------------------------------

kivy/graphics/vertex_instructions.pyx:299:22: C attributes cannot be added in implementation part of extension type defined in a pxd

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
            'points'.

    '''
    cdef list _vertices
    cdef list _indices
    cdef VertexFormat vertex_format
                     ^
------------------------------------------------------------

kivy/graphics/vertex_instructions.pyx:299:22: 'vertex_format' redeclared 

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...


cdef class StripMesh(VertexInstruction):
    cdef int icount
    cdef int li, lic
    cdef int add_triangle_strip(self, float *vertices, int vcount, int icount,
                              ^
------------------------------------------------------------

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/graphics/vertex_instructions.pxd:17:31: C method 'add_triangle_strip' is declared but not defined

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef list _vertices
    cdef list _indices
    cdef VertexFormat vertex_format
    cdef int is_built

    cdef void build_triangle_fan(self, float *vertices, int vcount, int icount)
                               ^
------------------------------------------------------------

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/kivy/graphics/vertex_instructions.pxd:27:32: C method 'build_triangle_fan' is declared but not defined
[INFO   ] Kivy v1.8.0
 /First/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'dependency_links'
   warnings.warn(msg)
 /First/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
   warnings.warn(msg)
kivy/graphics/vertex_instructions.c:1:2: error: #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
 #error Do not use this file, it is the result of a failed Cython compilation.
  ^
 error: command 'ccache' failed with exit status 1
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy" -d
```

Comment: Use `pip install Cython==0.17.1`

Comment: Cython is currently version 0.25.2.  Why would rolling back to 0.17.1 solve this issue?

Comment: @Jzl5325 It actually does!

Comment: @Juggernaut but why?  A significant amount of work went into version 0.18 - 0.25.  Did a regression occur?

Comment: @Jzl5325 I have no knowledge about how Cython works under the hood, I just now that rolling back to 0.17 solves this issue.

Comment: @Juggernaut apologies for the late response but I was taken up with other personal matters that came up. 
I have attempted this solution but no success I am seeing another cython compilation error.